# Get the index of the next word in the current line

Tags: vim

I would like to get the syntax group of the word under the cursor, or the next word under the cursor. My current code is this one :

```
let l:syntaxgroup = synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."), col("."), 1)), "name")
```

If we considere this Python code :

```
    def foo(self):
     ^ cursor is here
```

The syntax group is well detected : `Statement`. However, if we place the cursor right before like this :

```
    def foo(self):
  ^ cursor is here
```

The syntax group is not detected. Is there any way to get the position of the current/next word under the cursor instead of using the `col(".")` ?

---

EDIT: just a quick note : I would like to find the current/next **word** ; on the following situation (C), I should get the position of `double` :

```
double x = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
          ^ cursor is here
```

Answer (score 0):

To match the current pos in a word, or the next word if it doesn't match a word in the current pos, you can search for:

```
\v(\w|.{-}\zs\w)
```

So you can use the following func to get what you want:

```
fun! GetHLName() 
    " Defines the pattern:
    let l:pattern = printf('\v%%%dc(\w|.{-}\zs\w)', col('.'))

    " Stores either the column of the cursor, or the column of the next word:
    let l:col = match(getline('.'), l:pattern) + 1
        " (+1 because match() returns 0-based index)

    return synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."), l:col, 1)), "name")
endf
```

In the following source, `%%%dc` is replaced by `%23c`, `23` depending of `col('.')` : so it matches the current cursor column.